# Installing Mac VSCode extensions now failing with error: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found

Tags: visual-studio-code

After upgrading work Mac to Big Sur, now unable to install any VS Code extensions, where I was able to before. The error message that I am receiving is the following:

> [2021-08-18 14:04:53.663] [renderer1] [error] ["validating: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at x.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:54:201021)","    at async x.installGalleryExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:54:197524)","    at async vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:54:194563"]

I have looked at several stack overflow threads like this one:

[Error "end of central directory record signature not found" while installing ionide-fsharp in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41530269/error-end-of-central-directory-record-signature-not-found-while-installing-ion)

I can confirm the following:

1. My company runs a corporate transparent proxy, so I do not have to enter a proxy in the settings.  I've confirmed that I do not have this set.
2. I have followed the instructions to download and install the vsix file manually

   - Downloading looks to be successful, the python extension is 16.5 MB
   - The installation portion of the downloaded file fails with the same error
   - Confirmed that I do not have a disk space issues as someone mentioned in the above thread
3. I have reinstalled VSCode per these instructions: [How to completely uninstall vscode on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42603103/how-to-completely-uninstall-vscode-on-mac)

   - I've attempted installations of VSCode 1.59 (original version) and 1.58.2, same errors

Any suggestions on where to go from here?  I'm not able to install this locally, and can't seem to figure out what may be causing the issue.

I have confirmed with other team members that they're not running into my issue, and they have successfully upgraded to Big Sur.  I don't think that's the cause, but that's the only change to my workstation that I can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. Try downloading the vsix file of the extension from its github release page (make sure the extension version is compatible with your vscode version)
2. Disable your internet connection and install the vsix file via vscode.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this issue by doing the [manual install](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_install-from-a-vsix) via the command line (as opposed to through the VSCode app):

1. Download the .vsix file
2. use `code --install-extension <your-vsix-file>`

example: `code --install-extension ms-python.python-2023.6.0.vsix`

---

Just for context, here are the things I tried prior that *did not work*:

1. Installing through the "Extensions" marketplace in the VSCode app
2. Installing manually through the VSCode app with `ctrl+p` -> `"Extensions: Install from VSIX..."`