# "end of central directory record signature not found" when attempting to install C/C++ Extension Pack in vscode from Linux x64 RPM version on Fedora

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

From a fresh install of vscode (Linux x64 RPM version), Clicking install on the C/C++ Extension Pack gives:

```
2023-07-08 18:06:31.429 [error] Error: end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78388
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at w (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78374)
    at e.$kp.F (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:70278)
    at async e.$kp.C (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:67968)
    at async /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64795
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async e.$kp.z (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64742)
    at async e.$kp.installGalleryExtensions (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64175)
    at async e.$kp.installFromGallery (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:63496)

2023-07-08 18:06:31.476 [error] end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found: Error: end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78388
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at w (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78374)
    at e.$kp.F (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:70278)
    at async e.$kp.C (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:67968)
    at async /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64795
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async e.$kp.z (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64742)
    at async e.$kp.installGalleryExtensions (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64175)
    at async e.$kp.installFromGallery (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:63496)
```

attempting to install manually from `ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack` VSIX gives

````
2023-07-08 18:09:37.483 [error] end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found: Error: end of central directory record signature not found,end of central directory record signature not found
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78388
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at w (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:78374)
    at e.$kp.F (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:70278)
    at async e.$kp.C (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:67968)
    at async /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64795
    at async Promise.allSettled (index 0)
    at async e.$kp.z (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:79:64742)
    at async e.$kp.install (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/node/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:87:4931)```
````

Comment: related?: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42229, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/42079, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84869, https://stackoverflow.com/q/68837789/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41553002/11107541, https://stackoverflow.com/q/66134532/11107541

Answer (score 0):

For me turning off wifi, manually downloading ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack-1.3.0.vsix and running `code --install-extension ./Downloads/ms-vscode.cpptools-extension-pack-1.3.0.vsix` worked.